# SFML c++ / Не удаетстя запустить программу

Tags: c++, sfml

Библиотека SFML Graphics установлена через visual studio -> управление расширениями. Стандартный код:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML window");

while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
    window.display();
}

return 0;
```

При запуске ошибка.[image: скрин] Как её решить?

Так же список всех ошибок после вывода окна:

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::isOpen(void)const " (_*imp*?isOpen@Window@sf@@QBE_NXZ) в функции _main    PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)" (_*imp*?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z) в функции _main    PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (_*imp*??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) в функции _main  PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::close(void)" (_*imp*?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) в функции _main PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::Window::display(void)" (_*imp*?display@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) в функции _main PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (_*imp*??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z) в функции _main    PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char const *,class std::locale const &)" (_*imp*??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) в функции _main PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::~String(void)" (_*imp*??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main    PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (_*imp*??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) в функции _main   PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\main.obj 1

Comment: А она-то хоть успешно скомпилировалась?

Comment: В список ошибок выводится куча ошибок. https://imgur.com/a/mKHkDlm

Comment: Укажите ошибки в текстовом виде в вопросе и отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: Ну вот и ответ - она не запускается, потому что нечему запускаться... Библиотеки-то вы в проект, наверное, забыли включить?

Comment: Вопрос, как это сделать?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA+%D0%B2+Visual+C%2B%2B&oq=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA+%D0%B2+Visual+C%2B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6.13045j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Осталась 1 ошибка: 
Ошибка LNK1104 не удается открыть файл "sfml-main-d.lib" PixelGridEngine O:\C++\PixelGridEngine\PixelGridEngine\LINK 1